# Convolution of a $2$-dimensional function with a $1$-dimensional function

Tags: matrices, convolution, signal-processing, image-processing

Below is the schematic diagram from a very [popular paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neuroimage.2007.09.034) in this field of [retinotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinotopy).

[image: diagram from Dumoulin & Wandell]

In the diagram above, $g$ is a bivariate Gaussian function of the form

$$ g (x,y) = \exp \left( - \left( \frac{ (x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right) \right) $$

Initially, we multiply the functions $g$ and $s$ and then sum over $x$ and $y$,

$$ r (t) = \sum_{x,y} s (x, y, t) g (x,y) $$

Then, we compute the convolution of $r$ and $h$ (the hemodynamic response function (HRF)),

$$ p (t) = (r \ast h) (t) $$
**Question:**

My main problem is in the following part of the above diagram:

[image]

As per the above snippet, at any time $t$, the function $r(t)$ represents a $2$-dimensional slice in spatial domain, though I may be wrong. But if I am right, how can we convolve $r$ with $h$?

Or could it be that the function $r(t)$ is representing a single value which is basically the **area** under the pizza-slice?

I think that $r(t)$ can be written as $r(x,y,t)$. Is it so? If so, it simply means that at any time $t$, the function $r(x,y,t)$ represents a $2$-dimensional matrix and the HRF function represent a single scalar value. But the result of convolving a 2D matrix with a single scalar value would not be a single value.

I need some explanation how are we constructing the function $p(t)$ by convolving $r(t)$ with HRF?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147702/discussion-on-question-by-skm-convolution-of-a-2-dimensional-function-with-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.